# how to save an uploaded file named in persian characters with php?

Tags: php, preg-replace, special-characters, farsi

I want to replace the special characters by " " it means only alphabetical and numeric characters are supported, this code worked so far!

```
function clean($string) {
   return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', ' ', $string);
}
```

but now when I try to allow persian (farsi) characters as well, the problem happens which is the $string becomes empty! and when I tried to use other examples given by users for example:

```
function clean($string) {
return preg_replace('/([^A-Za-z0-9 ])-(^[\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]*$)/', ' ', $string);
}
```

the file name saves as Ø§Ø°ØªØ§ØªØ§.

any ideas on how can I solve this?

thank you in advance!

Comment: First of all you should check what character encoding the underlying file system uses …

Comment: Using `Persian` characters in file names is not a good idea, specially in Internet. Many systems does not have full support of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got the answer on my own, the files were getting saved just right, the problem was that my server didn't have utf-8 so it was showing me these characters, and as for having to limit the user to only use english and persian alphabet and number I came up with this solution:

```
$('input').keypress(function( e ) {    
    if(!/([ابپتثجچحخدذرزژشسصضطظعغفقکگلمنوهیء a-zA-Z0-9])+/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which)))
        return false;
});
```